# How are passwords encrypted in AzerothCore? Is it same as Trinitycore?

Tags: php, azerothcore

I am trying to build a web portal which is using **SOAP RBAC** (3.3.5a) to communicate between **wow server** and **web portal**.

What encryption is AzerothCore using? Is it same as Trinity?

I tried using other CMS existing FusionGen and github and looking at login and registration system. They all base on trinity.

But it seems its not actually same somehow.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AzerothCore uses the same strategy of all MaNGOS-based game servers. So, yes, it's the same as in TrinityCore too.

Passwords are encrypted using the [SHA1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hash function with the format: `account:password` in uppercase.

So if your account is `squeeze` and your password is `azeroth`, it will be encrypted in `SHA1('SQEEZE:AZEROTH')`.

The password will be stored in the `sha_pass_hash` field of the `account` table inside the `acore_auth` database.

SQL code

```
SELECT SHA1(CONCAT(UPPER('your_username'), ':', UPPER('your_password')))
```

PHP code

```
sha1(strtoupper($username).':'.strtoupper($password));
```

Comment: SHA1 salted with your username.. that is a HORRIBLE password storage scheme, if a hacker breaches that database, it'll be very easy to run a bruteforce attack with modern GPUs to recover shorter passwords, and running dictionary attacks on those hashes can be done on a laptop. someone should really teach those devs about [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)

Comment: @hanshenrik I agree, that was implemented a long ago. Being an open source project, feel free to open a PR and change it

Comment: where is the repo and what language is it written in?

Answer (score 1):

@hanshenrik let's slow down. I do agree that it is a HORRIBLE password storage scheme but for slice differents reasons. Salts defend against a pre-computed hash attack, so in case an attacker is able to breach your DB, he will have access to the salt anyway, so the attack described it's not really depending from the use of the account as salt, even though I do agree that must always be a truly unique long enough random sequence of bit, (the account name could be very short and public).
The real problem here are 2:

1) SHA1 is no longer considered secure
2) Make the password insensitive reduce the possible combination.

For a hardened scheme would be nice to encrypt even the salt to make the life harder to an attacker.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are more information about passwords:

http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/account#sha_pass_hash

In AZerothCore database (and all Mangos derivates) the SHA1 is only used to store password in database but the game client uses an SRP6 protocol that needs v and s keys generated by the server and sent to the client.